# Can I replace a part of the text in a TextView for a Image in Android?

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview

The question is pretty much exactly what I want, lets say i have this text:

"{W}, {T}: Tap target creature."

I have to replace the {W} and the {T} for 2 tiny little images pretty much the same size of the 3 letters(in case {W} and {T})... Is that possible in some way?

Just to say, the TextView is inside a Listview...

the Position for {W} and {T} are not always the same...

the images are in my resource...

Comment: Have a look at spans and the spannable interface, [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177) is a small introduction. Especially check out that ImageSpan smiley example.

Answer (score 0):

The one workaround you can try is to place your `TextView` and `ImageView` inside a `FrameLayout`, one on top of the other. Now when you want to change them, just make one of them invisible and initialize the other. This will probably work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the attribute drawableLeft of the text view? But since you have two images, you will have to use a single image file which consists of both {w}{t}. so you will have to put the images with all combinations of {w}{t} in your resources.

then use the following method in your code:

textView.setCompoundDrawables(leftDrawable, null, null, null);